# Xamarin Forms: How to implement an image carousel in 2019

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Has anyone been able to successfully implement an image slider in 2019? All the solutions that I find seem to reference some outdated Nuget package which is no longer available. Basically, I would like to add a section to my ContentPage where a background image will change continuously (likely in a timed manner).

Comment: [CardsView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CardsView/) has a carousel option, which has been updated 2 days ago

Comment: Xamarin.Forms 4 now offers a [CarouselView](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-4-0-feature-preview-an-entirely-new-point-of-collectionview/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own control based on horizontal ScrollView. For example, create ContentView (with xaml) like this:

```
public partial class View1 : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CollectionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Collection), typeof(List<ProxyObject>),
        typeof(View1), default(List<ProxyObject>), BindingMode.OneWay, propertyChanged: OnCollectionPropertyChanged);

    private static void OnCollectionPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (!(bindable is View1 view1))
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (var item in newValue as List<ProxyObject>)
        {
            view1.stackLayout.Children.Add(new Label());
        }
    }

    public List<ProxyObject> Collection
    {
        get { return (List<ProxyObject>)GetValue(CollectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CollectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public View1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TcuClientStandard.Helpers.Views.View1">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout" Orientation="Horizontal">                    
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

This is a sample for reference.